# Why do dbcc checkdb on system databases and sp_executesql on a user database cause a deadlock?

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks, dbcc

I have a daily job running a dbcc checkdb statement without additional parameters on each of the system databases. This job runs during off-peak hours and usually takes 5 seconds or less to run.

The last run however, took only 1 second and failed because of a deadlock. I've got an alert that saves me an xml graph of the deadlock, which I'm including for more detailed info.

My main questions are: why does such a deadlock actually occur and is it avoidable?

```
    <TextData>
      <deadlock-list>
     <deadlock victim="process290fd861088">
      <process-list>
       <process id="process290fd861088" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 2:5:0 " ownerId="1250115008" transactionname="CheckDb" lasttranstarted="2017-03-20T01:00:01.427" XDES="0x2b277040bd8" lockMode="S" schedulerid="7" kpid="12760" status="suspended" spid="78" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2017-03-20T01:00:00.060" lastbatchcompleted="2017-03-20T01:00:00.060" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.060" clientapp="SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0xB425122DD6C28D4BBE42D7F0AF76FC40 : Step 1)" hostname="0000-DB-0000" hostpid="8040" loginname="0000\0000" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1250115008" currentdb="2" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
        <executionStack>
         <frame procname="0000_Local.server.CheckSystemDatabases" line="19" stmtstart="740" stmtend="776" sqlhandle="0x030006006a934a11b3ebcd0023a7000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    dbcc checkdb(@dbId     </frame>
         <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="70" sqlhandle="0x010006006688101b405fcfceb602000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    exec [server].[CheckSystemDatabases     </frame>
        </executionStack>
        <inputbuf>
    exec [server].[CheckSystemDatabases];    </inputbuf>
       </process>
       <process id="process2b59a715468" taskpriority="0" logused="952" waitresource="OBJECT: 2:3:0 " ownerId="1250114957" transactionname="droptemp" lasttranstarted="2017-03-20T01:00:01.423" XDES="0x29b8755ce58" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="8" kpid="9440" status="suspended" spid="67" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2017-03-20T01:00:01.410" lastbatchcompleted="2017-03-20T01:00:01.410" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.410" clientapp="0000-API-0000" hostname="0000-0000-WEB-0000" hostpid="42180" loginname="0000\0000" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="0" currentdb="9" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
        <executionStack>
         <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    sp_executesql     </frame>
         <frame procname="0000.dbo.SomeProcName" line="93" stmtstart="8320" stmtend="8496" sqlhandle="0x030009002ac137082fa8b20029a7000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
    exec sp_executesql @selectSql, N'@rowcount int output', @rowcount = @TotalRowCount outpu     </frame>
        </executionStack>
        <inputbuf>
    Proc [Database Id = 9 Object Id = 137871658]    </inputbuf>
       </process>
      </process-list>
      <resource-list>
       <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="5" subresource="FULL" dbid="2" objectname="tempdb.sys.sysrowsets" id="lock2b4103b8380" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="5">
        <owner-list>
         <owner id="process2b59a715468" mode="IX" />
        </owner-list>
        <waiter-list>
         <waiter id="process290fd861088" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
        </waiter-list>
       </objectlock>
       <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="3" subresource="FULL" dbid="2" objectname="tempdb.sys.sysrscols" id="lock291f3d8a900" mode="S" associatedObjectId="3">
        <owner-list>
         <owner id="process290fd861088" mode="S" />
        </owner-list>
        <waiter-list>
         <waiter id="process2b59a715468" mode="IX" requestType="wait" />
        </waiter-list>
       </objectlock>
      </resource-list>
     </deadlock>
    </deadlock-list></TextData>
```

**Solution i have implemented to priortize user transactions over Daily checkDB for TempDB:**

```
set nocount on;  
set deadlock_priority low;  
 declare @dbId int;  
declare loopCheckDB cursor fast_forward   
for select [d].[database_id] from [sys].[databases] as [d] where   [d].[database_id] < 5  
 order by [d].[name]  
 open [loopCheckDB]   
fetch next from [loopCheckDB] into @dbId;   
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
 begin dbcc checkdb(@dbId); 
fetch next from [loopCheckDB] into @dbId; 
end 
close [loopCheckDB];
 deallocate [loopCheckDB];
```

Comment: Following up on the answer given by @TheGameiswar , I'm also posting the solution I've implemented.

I'm still checking tempdb, but now have give the procedure I'm using a lower deadlock priority. The idea is that user transactions should be prioritised over a daily system check, more specifically that of tempdb. Seeing that a deadlock scenario like this, is only occurring sporadically, it seems like a viable choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do dbcc checkdb on system databases and sp_executesql on a user database cause a deadlock?

DBCC checkDB acquired Intent Exclusive lock on `tempdb.sys.sysrowsets` and is waiting for  a sharedlock on `tempdb.sys.sysrscols`..

your user proc,is also accessing TEMPDB resources.This user proc acquired IX lock on tempdb.sys.sysrscols and is waiting for a shared lock on  tempdb.sys.sysrowsets..

Thus Deadlock occurred and this is a simple case of deadlock

Normally,DBCC CheckDB takes snapshot of the database before analysis and it works  on this snapshot to avoid locking,blocking..

In this case,[as per this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/261d1211-7413-42ed-ab88-c71b9f81a32d/dbcc-could-not-obtain-a-lock-on-this-object-because-the-lock-request-timeout-period-was-exceeded?forum=sqldisasterrecovery&prof=required)..Snapshot is not possible with TEMPDB  and so in your case,there are incompatible locks acquired by both the transactions ,which is the reason for the deadlock you saw.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @TheGameiswar. It makes perfect sense that tempdb was in the middle of this deadlock like you said.

I was under the assumption that the dbcc checkdb statement would create a snapshot, but overlooked the tempdb exception.